# How many different ways can a number N be expressed as a sum of K different positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many different ways can a number $n \in N$ be expressed as a sum of $k$ different positive numbers?

Comment: How is this problem different than finding the "number of partitions of $n$ into $m$ distinct parts"? (see [A008289](https://oeis.org/A008289)) Answers here seem to use advanced tools compared to formulas on OEIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We  show how  to  establish a  recurrene for  the  number $Q(n,k)$  of
partitions  of  $n$  into  $k$  different parts  where  order  is  not
important. (If  it were  and with  all parts  distinct  we  could just
multiply by  $k!.$) Using the  Polya Enumeration Theorem (PET)  we get
for the answer that it is given by

$$[z^n] Z(P_k)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$

where  $Z(P_k)$  is the  cycle  index  of  the unlabled  set  operator
$\mathfrak{P}_{=k}$ with OGF

$$G(w) = \exp\left(a_1 w - a_2 \frac{w^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{w^3}{3} - \right)
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} a_l (-1)^{l-1} \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

Differentiating we obtain

$$G'(w) = G(w) 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} a_l (-1)^{l-1} w^{l-1}\right).$$

Extracting coefficients on [w^k] we find

$$(k+1) Z(P_{k+1}) = 
\sum_{q=0}^k [w^{k-q}] G(w) 
[w^q] \sum_{l\ge 1} a_l (-1)^{l-1} w^{l-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k Z(P_{k-q}) a_{q+1} (-1)^q
= \sum_{q=1}^{k+1} Z(P_{k+1-q}) a_{q} (-1)^{q-1}.$$

We get the recurrence

$$Z(P_k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{q=1}^{k} Z(P_{k-q}) a_{q} (-1)^{q-1}$$

with $Z(P_0) = 1.$ This yields for the present case that the substituted
cycle index

$$L_k(z) = Z(P_k)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$

has recurrence

$$L_k(z) = \frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{q=1}^{k} L_{k-q}(z) \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} (-1)^{q-1}.$$

Extracting the coefficient on $[z^n]$ we obtain

$$Q_{n,k} = \frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{q=1}^{k} [z^n] L_{k-q}(z) \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} (-1)^{q-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{q=1}^{k} [z^{n-q}] L_{k-q}(z) \frac{1}{1-z^q} (-1)^{q-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{q=1}^{k}  (-1)^{q-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/q\rfloor - 1} 
Q_{n-(p+1)q, k-q}.$$

The boundary conditions here are $Q_{0,0}  = 1$ and $Q_{n,0} = Q_{0,k}
= 0$  and $Q_{n,1} = 1.$  There is a non-essential  boundary condition
which is that $Q_{n,k} = 0$ when $n \lt \frac{1}{2} k(k+1).$

Observe that we  can obtain an alternate form of  the recurrence by
writing

$$\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{q=1}^{k}  (-1)^{q-1} 
\sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor n/q\rfloor} 
Q_{n-pq, k-q}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{k}
\sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{q|m\wedge q\le k} (-1)^{q-1} Q_{n-m, k-q}.}$$

This yields the following Maple routine:

```
with(numtheory);

Q :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;

    if n=0 and k=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=0 or k=0  then return 0 fi;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;

    if n < 1/2*k*(k+1) then return 0 fi;

    1/k*add((-1)^(q-1)*
            add(Q(n-(p+1)*q, k-q), p=0..floor(n/q)-1),
            q=1..k);
end;


QX :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;

    if k < 0 then return 0 fi;

    if n=0 and k=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=0 or k=0  then return 0 fi;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;

    if n < 1/2*k*(k+1) then return 0 fi;

    1/k*add(add((-1)^(q-1)*Q(n-m, k-q), q in divisors(m)),
            m=1..n);
end;


A := n -> add(Q(n,k), k=1..floor(sqrt(2*n)));
AX := n -> add(QX(n,k), k=1..floor(sqrt(2*n)));
```

This will produce the following  sequence for the number of partitions
into any number of distinct parts:

$$1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 
\\ 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142, 165, 192, 222, 256, 296,\ldots $$

which  points  us  to [OEIS  A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009)  where
these data are confirmed. We get the following sequence for partitions
into seven  distinct parts starting at  $n=-1 + 1/2\times 7\times  8 =
27:$

$$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 21, 28, 38, 49, 65, 82, 105, 131,
\\ 164, 201, 248, 300, 364, 436, 522, 618, 733, 860, 1009,\ldots$$

which   points  to   [OEIS  A008636](https://oeis.org/A008636)   which
again confirms the data and lists additional references.

**Addendum.** Starting from the generating function (first principles)
we  extract  coefficients  for  an  efficient  recurrence  for  strict
partitions into any number of parts:

$$P(x) = \prod_{q\ge 1} (1+x^q)$$

Differentiatinng we get

$$P'(x) = P(x) \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{qx^{q-1}}{1+x^q}$$

and on extracting coefficients we find

$$(n+1) P_{n+1} = \sum_{m=0}^n P_{n-m} [x^m]
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{qx^{q-1}}{1+x^q}
\\ = \sum_{m=0}^n P_{n-m} 
\sum_{q\ge 1} q [x^{m+1-q}] \frac{1}{1+x^q}
\\ = \sum_{m=0}^n P_{n-m} 
\sum_{q=1}^{m+1} q [x^{m+1-q}] \frac{1}{1+x^q}
\\ = \sum_{m=0}^n P_{n-m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{m} (q+1) [x^{m-q}] \frac{1}{1+x^{q+1}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (q+1)
\sum_{m=q}^{n}  P_{n-m}  [x^{m-q}] \frac{1}{1+x^{q+1}}.$$

This implies $m-q = p(q+1)$ with $p\ge 0$ and where
$m\le n$ or $p(q+1)+q \le n$ so that 
$p\le \lfloor (n+1)/(q+1)\rfloor -1$ and we obtain

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (q+1)
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/(q+1)\rfloor -1}
P_{n-p(q+1)-q}
[x^{p(q+1)}] \frac{1}{1+x^{q+1}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (q+1)
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/(q+1)\rfloor -1}
P_{n-p(q+1)-q} (-1)^{p}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (q+1)
\sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/(q+1)\rfloor}
P_{n-(p-1)(q+1)-q} (-1)^{p+1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (q+1)
\sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/(q+1)\rfloor}
P_{n+1-p(q+1)} (-1)^{p+1}
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} q
\sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/q\rfloor}
P_{n+1-pq} (-1)^{p+1}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P_{n+1-k} 
\sum_{p|k} \frac{k}{p} (-1)^{p+1}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P_{n+1-k}
\sum_{p|k} p (-1)^{k/p+1}.$$

This finally yields a linear recurrence which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
P_n = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} P_{n-k}
\sum_{p|k} p (-1)^{k/p+1}}$$

where $P_0 = 1.$

Now for the inner sum its Dirichlet series is evidently
given by

$$-\zeta(s-1) \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}
= -\zeta(s-1) \left(\frac{2}{2^s}-1\right)\zeta(s).$$

Multiplication by $\zeta(s)$ is summing  over the divisors in terms of
Dirichlet series  so we need to  examine the product of  the first two
terms. We get that for $n$  even the term $1/n^s$ appears twice, first
paired with $-2\times  n/2$ and second with $n$  for a contribution of
zero. For  $n$ odd the term appears  just once paired with  $n$, for a
contribution  of $n.$  Hence  the inner  sum  is the  sum  of the  odd
divisors of $k$ and we get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
P_n = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} P_{n-k}
\sum_{p|k\wedge p\;\text{odd}} p.}$$

Comment: Do you have an upper bound for $Q_{n, k}$?

Comment: Good question. The OEIS entry has the asymptotics.

Comment: I found the asymptotics for the sum of the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts in the OEIS entry. But, I need the asymptotics for the sum of the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts. I post that question in:

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078090/upper-bound-for-the-strict-partition-on-k-summands

Answer (score 0):

As noted by *Marko Riedel* we can limit the analysis to $Q(n,k)$ = number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts, where order is not important.
That is to say: *Number of strictly increasing sequences, of $k$ terms, with sum = $n$*, or
 (changing parameters notation for better clearness) 
$$
\begin{gathered}
  Q(s,q) = \text{No}\text{.}\,\text{of}\,\text{sol}\text{.}\,\text{of}\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 < x_{\,1}  < x_{\,2}  <  \cdots  < x_{\,\,q}  \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,q} {x_{\,j}  = s}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \text{No}\text{.}\,\text{of}\,\text{sol}\text{.}\,\text{of}\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 < y_{\,j} \left( { \leqslant s} \right)\quad \left| {\;1 \leqslant j \leqslant q} \right. \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,q} {j\;y_{\,j} }  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \text{No}\text{.}\,\text{of}\,\text{sol}\text{.}\,\text{of}\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant z_{\,j} \left( { < s} \right)\quad \left| {\;1 \leqslant j \leqslant q} \right. \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,q} {j\;z_{\,j} }  = s - \frac{{q\left( {q + 1} \right)}}
{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} \tag{1}
$$
where the 2nd step comes from taking $y_{j}=x_{q-j+1}-x_{q-j} \; | \; x_0=0$.
We define Q to be non null only for positive value of the parameters, and to be $=1$ for the empty word $s=0,\;q=0$.
$$
Q(s < 0,q) = 0\quad Q(s,q < 0) = 0\quad Q(0,q) = [q = 0]
$$
(the square brackets indicating the *Iverson Bracket*)
so that it corresponds to the double generating function
$$
G(x,y) = \sum\limits_{\begin{subarray}{l} 
  0 \leqslant \,q \\ 
  0 \leqslant \,s\, 
\end{subarray}}  {Q(s,q)\;x^{\,s} \;y^{\,q} }  = \prod\limits_{1 \leqslant \,k} {\left( {1 + y\,x^{\,k} } \right)} \tag{2}
$$
From the second relation in (1) it is easy to deduce the recurrence
$$
Q(s,\;q) = \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant \,j\,\,\left( {\, \leqslant \,\,\left\lfloor {s/q} \right\rfloor \,\, \leqslant \,\,s\,} \right)} {Q(s - q\,j,\;q - 1)}  + \left[ {s = 0} \right]\left[ {q = 0} \right]  \tag{3}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Number of integer partitions of a number n, denoted by p(n), is much harder to find and no easy formula available.

This [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Partition_(number_theory)&oldid=682278876#Algorithm) gives various algorithms for finding p(n)

Approximate value for p(n) can be found using Hardy-Ramanujan Asymptotic Partition Formula
$p(n) \approx \dfrac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}e^\left(\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{3}}\right)$

This [tool](http://comnuan.com/cmnn02/cmnn02001/) generates number of integer partitions online and is very useful

This [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18365/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-bell-numbers-the-bell-polynomials-and-the) is also is related to this.

Comment: Is it not also required that a particular integer appear in the partition only once?

Comment: a particular integer can appear more than one time. for example, one of the integer partitions of $3$ can be $1,1,1$

Comment: Though interesting, this fails to answer the question, which specifically asks for each integer to appear at most once.

Comment: @goblin, i believe, the question was edited after I answered and when I answered, the word 'different'  was not there. Not sure though and I cannot verify now.

Comment: @Kiran, fair enough. Just one of the flaws in the website design, I suppose