# Upper bound for the strict partition on K summands

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

In number theory and combinatorics, a partition of a positive integer $n$, also called an integer partition, is a way of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers. Partitions into distinct parts are sometimes called "strict partitions". Is there a polynomial upper bound for the strict partition on $K$ summands?

Comment: What kind of upper bound do you want? $n^K$ is a trivial upper bound if you want any.

Comment: Thanks!! I change the question!!

Comment: As you may know, strict partitions correspond bijectively to partitions into odd parts.

Comment: According to https://oeis.org/A000009 the number $q(n)$ of strict partitions of $n$ grows exponentially; asymptotically
$$q(n) \sim \frac{\exp(\pi\sqrt{n/3-1/72})}{4\sqrt[4]{3(n-1/24)^3}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a computational approach to the problem. Recall the discussion
from                 the                 following                [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077769/)    where   the
formula

$$[z^n] Z(P_k)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$

was applied  and a  recurrence for $Z(P_k)$  was given. As  an example
consider $Z(P_5)$ which is

$$Z(P_5) = {\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}}{120}}-1/12\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}
+1/6\,a_{{3}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}
\\-1/4\,a_{{4}}a_{{1}}-1/6\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}+1/5\,a_{{5}}$$

The substituted cycle index then becomes

$$Z(P_5)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right) =
{\frac {{z}^{5}}{120\, \left( 1-z \right) ^{5}}}-1/12\,{\frac {{z}^
{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}
\\+1/6\,{
\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{2}
}}+1/8\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( 1-z \right)  \left( -{z}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}-1/4\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{4}+1 \right)
 \left( 1-z \right) }}
\\-1/6\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right) }}+1/5\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{-{z}^{
5}+1}}.$$

*We  proceed to  an  important observation.*  Suppose  we convert  the
substituted cycle index as shown in the example to its maximal partial
fraction decomposition (which means  going to complex roots, and these
are  all roots  of  unity).  We  seek  to extract  the coefficient  on
$[z^n].$  Considering  a particular  term  from  the partial  fraction
decomposition we have with $\zeta$ a root of unity that

$$[z^n] \frac{z^q}{(z-\zeta)^p} =
[z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{\zeta^p} \frac{1}{(z/\zeta-1)^p}
= (-1)^p \frac{1}{\zeta^p} {n-q+p-1\choose p-1} \zeta^{-(n-q)}.$$

Note furthermore that on adding $\lambda = \mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,k)$
to $n$ all roots of  unity have simultaneously returned to their value
at $n$ and this is the smallest offset to produce this phenomenon. The
powers of the  different $\zeta$ have morphed into  a constant, and we
obtain a polynomial from the  binomial coefficients. The degree of the
polynomial  is   $k-1$  as  obtained   from  the  term   $a_1^k/k!   =
(z/(1-z))^k/k!.$  Therefore  we  immediately conclude  that  $Q_{n,k}$
(notation  from the  cited post)  is  asymptotic to  $n^{k-1}$ with  a
constant to be determined.

We can compute these polynomials  by interpolating using the values of
$Q_{n,k}$ from  the recurrence. We get $\lambda$  different formulae /
cases, each of degree $k-1.$ The following Maple code does this.

```
Q :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;

    if n=0 and k=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=0 or k=0  then return 0 fi;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;

    if n < 1/2*k*(k+1) then return 0 fi;

    1/k*add((-1)^(q-1)*
            add(Q(n-(p+1)*q, k-q), p=0..floor(n/q)-1),
            q=1..k);
end;

PSEQ :=
proc(k)
    option remember;
    local n, lambda, l, res, locs, vals;

    res := [];
    lambda := lcm(seq(q, q=1..k));

    for l from 1 to lambda do
        locs := [seq(l+p*lambda, p=0..k-1)];
        vals := map(loc -> Q(loc, k), locs);

        res :=
        [op(res),
         unapply(interp(locs, vals, n), n)];
    od;

    res;
end;

X :=
proc(n, k)
    local Fseq, lambda, idx;

    Fseq := PSEQ(k);
    lambda := nops(Fseq);

    idx := n mod lambda;
    if idx = 0 then idx := idx + lambda; fi;

    op(idx, Fseq)(n);
end;

SIM := (n,k)->binomial(n-1,k-1)/k!;
```

This  will produce the  following sequence  of polynomials  for $k=5,$
listed    according    to    the    remainder   upon    division    by
$\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5)= 60$ starting with remainder one (zero residue represented by $\lambda.$)

```
> PSEQ(5);
              4         3   31   2   41     949
[n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                            288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     181
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     305
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     576

                 4         3   31   2   11     27
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     40

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     141
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     55
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     72

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 4/5,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     49
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      96     64

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     27
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     40

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 8/9,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     141
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 4/5,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     305
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     576

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     181
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 7/8,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     141
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     377
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     576

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 4/5,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     181
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 8/9,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     27
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     40

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     41
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      96     64

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 4/5,
                               288      24

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     55
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     72

                 4         3   31   2   41     181
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     949
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11     27
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     40

                 4         3   31   2   41     377
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     576

                 4         3   31   2   11     31
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + --,
                               288      24     45

                 4         3   31   2   41     141
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      96     320

                 4         3   31   2   11     203
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ---,
                               288      24     360

                 4         3   31   2   41     1309
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + ----,
                               288      96     2880

                 4         3   31   2   11
    n -> 1/2880 n  - 1/96 n  + --- n  - -- n + 1]
                               288      24
```

Surprise! We are  now able to compute $Q_{n,8}$  with $n$ from $16000$
to $16008$ which is out of reach of the recurrence and we get

$$1310588091362349970144, 1311162227425710083350, 
\\ 1311736579060069106145, 1312311146331986804908, 
\\ 1312885929309812275982, 1313460928060138717214,
\\ 1314036142651349327782, 1314611573150070750093, 
\\ 1315187219624720299308,\ldots$$

Extracting the leading coefficients we obtain the sequence

```
> seq(lcoeff(op(1,PSEQ(k))(n)), k=1..8);
        1, 1/2, 1/12, 1/144, 1/2880, 1/86400, 1/3628800, 1/203212800
```

This is [OEIS A010790](https://oeis.org/A010790) or

$$(k-1)! \times k!.$$

What this says is that the dominant asymptotic originates with 
$a_1^k/k!$ which gives

$$\frac{1}{k!} [z^n] \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}
= \frac{1}{k!} [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
= \frac{1}{k!} {n-k+k-1\choose k-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{(k-1)! \times k!} (n-1)^{\underline{k-1}}.$$

We thus finally conjecture that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Q_{n,k} \sim \frac{1}{(k-1)! \times k!} (n-1)^{\underline{k-1}}.}$$

This      post     received      some     basic      input     from
[mathpages.com](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath556/kmath556.htm).

Comment: Instructive answer! (+1)

Comment: Thank you! I recall you saying you were interested in learning more about cycle indices.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks Marko!

Answer (score 0):

**If $K$ is fixed, yes.**  The paper *An Asymptotic Formula in the Theory of Partitions* by G Szekeres states both an upper and lower bound using the notation "$q(n,k)$, the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ positive unequal parts."
[image]

**If $K$ grows with $n$, then no.** The same paper goes on to describe the case where $K$ is allowed to grow with $n$ up to $K = O(\sqrt{n})$.

[image]

And in a follow-up paper, *Some Asymptotic Formulae in the Theory of Partitions (II)* by G. Szekeres, he identifies the $K$ which maximizes $q(n, K)$ asymptotically as $n$ tends to infinity.

[image]